# sorting different types of variables in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Here we have 2 types of variables in an array and one being an integer while the other being a string , I am trying to sort the array via alphabetical order or by the length of the string but it keeps detecting the integer over the string first.

```js
    const val=[{
      x:"second",
      y:2
     },{
      x:"first",
      y:1
    }];   
    function compare(a,b){return b.length-a.length};
    val.sort(compare);
    console.log(val);
```

Comment: Objects don't have a `length` property unless explicitly defined (which is not the case here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/q/979256/9775003)

Comment: *"variables in an array"*: you mean (property) values. Variables are different things.

Comment: yea i meant properties* value thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are finding the length of the object not the object key `x` so you need to change your `a.length` to `a.x.length` and `b.length` to `b.x.length`

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const val=[{
      x:"second",
      y:2
     },{
      x:"first",
      y:1
    }];   
    function compare(a,b){return a.x.length-b.x.length};
    val.sort(compare);
    console.log(val);
```

You need to compare the property and not the object. Also you might want to handle all the scenarios of -1, 0 and 1 for the callback. I'll leave that to you. Have a look at existing similar questions.